# what am I doing wrong with this switch statment?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, logic

I have it working in an *If/else* statement. I am trying to convert it into a switch statement but I am having trouble. I don't seem to be getting any errors in the console when I run it. I should be able to input current lat and lon and where I want to go in lat and lon and the output should be a direction

```
function caseSwitch(intCurrentLatitude, intCurrentLongitude, intDestinationLatitude, intDestinationLongitude){
//var intCurrentLatitude = parseFloat(prompt("What is your current Latitude?"));
//var intCurrentLongitude = parseFloat(prompt("What is your current Longitude?"));
//var intDestinationLatitude = parseFloat(prompt("What is your destination Latitude?"));
//var intDestinationLongitude = parseFloat(prompt("What is your destination longitude?"));

    var Latitude = intCurrentLatitude;
    var longitude = intCurrentLongitude;

        var latitude_end = intDestinationLatitude;
        var longitude_end = intDestinationLongitude;
        var output = document.getElementById("case/switchConstruct");

        var end = intDestinationLatitude - latitdue;
        var end2 = intDestinationLongitude - longitude;

        switch (true){
            case (end  > 0 && end2 > 0) :

                output.textContent = "We'd be headed North East, capt'n!";
                break;
            case(end > 0 && end2 < 0) :

                output.textContent = "Ye'd best head North West, captain!";
                break;
            case(end < 0 && end2 > 0) :

                output.textContent = "Ye'd best head South East, captain!";
                break;
            case(end < 0 && end2 < 0) :

                output.textContent = "Ye'd best head South West, captain!";
                break;
            case(end === 0 && end2 === 0) :

                output.textContent = "Ye'd best head some direction, captain!";
                break;
            case(end < 0 && end2 === 0) :

                output.textContent = "Ye'd best head South, captain!";
                break;
            case(end > 0 && end2  === 0) :

                output.textContent = "Ye'd best head North, captain!";
                break;
            case(end === 0 && end2 < 0) :

                output.textContent = "Ye'd best head West, captain!";
                break;
            case(end === 0 && end2 > 0) :

                output.textContent = "Ye'd best head East, captain!";
                break;
            default :

                output.textContent = "Capt'n, give us better directions!?!";
                break;
            }

    }
```

Comment: Well one problem is that you spelled "latitude" as `Latitude` when you declared the variable, and `latitdue` when you used it a few lines later.

Comment: why not console.log() and see where the problem is?  or give us an example input and expected output?

Comment: You really *should* be using an `if`/`else` cascade. It's much easier to read, shorter, simpler and less error-prone than this `switch` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything works fine , you just spelled Latitude wrong....

**Change :**

```
 var end = intDestinationLatitude - latitdue;
```

**To:**

```
var end = intDestinationLatitude - Latitude;
```

**or vice versa...javascript is case sensitive...**

Working here:

http://codepen.io/theConstructor/pen/OXVxbK?editors=1010

Hope this helps